# Why is this MySQL CREATE TABLE statement failing?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, mysql-workbench, create-table

This create statement is failing, and I can't see the reason.  MySQL reports:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,  `objObjectType` VARCHAR(100) ' at line 3*

```
CREATE TABLE `my_object_attribute_map` (
`objID` INT(10) UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL primary key,
`objForeignKey` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
`objObjectType` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
`objTypeName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
`objLabel` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
`objValue` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
`objDateCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`objCreatorID` CHAR(32) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci        
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `not null` constraint goes *after* the character set and collation:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_object_attribute_map` (
    `objID` INT(10) UNSIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL primary key,
    `objForeignKey` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `objObjectType` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't know that.

Comment: Quoting doesn't make any difference in case sensitivity, either at the time of create or later, and camelCase doesn't make quoting any more needed than camel_case  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=ae8053b8cc80969ca6ec5eca3cfef5ae

Comment: @ysth: thank for the demo, which does makes your point. I wrongly assumed that databases are consistent in that regard, whereas obviously it is not the case: it is happening in Oracle and Postgres (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f73b1105687d26c58ca65026ac623eda), but not in MySQL. I removed that part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of column definitions has some warts; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html.

Basically, the CHARACTER SET is part of the data type, and must come before the NOT NULL, which is an extra attribute that applies to any type.  COLLATE I believe in principle is also part of the data type, and should also come before NOT NULL, but if you do specify it afterwards it still works (or is ignored, for non-string types), presumably for backwards compatibility.

Since the collation set also determines the character set, you could just leave character set out and specify COLLATE wherever you want.